# How can i search in datatables - data loading with ajax/serverside

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, servlets

i´m new to datatables.
I have the problem, that when i start tipping a word into the 'searchfield' of the table the 'processing' loading label is show.
I load my data with ajax in my table.
So - what must i do, that i can search in my table?
I think i must set up a ajax call, isn´t is?

Tanks for helping me:)

Here the codes:

```
var table;
$(function(){
var table = $('#datatables').DataTable({
     "dom": 'TC<"clear">Rlfrtip',
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": {
     "url": "get_data", 
     "type": "GET"  
     },
...
```

And here is my serlet:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ordering";
    int rows=0;

    JSONArray arrayback = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orders?user=***&password=****");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        rows= meta.getColumnCount();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            array.add(rs.getString("id"));
            array.add(rs.getString("employeName"));
            array.add(rs.getString("employeAdresse"));
            arrayback.add(array);
        }

        object.put("data", arrayback);
        object.put("draw", 1);
        object.put("recordsTotal", rows);
        object.put("recordsFiltered", rows);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        out.print(object);          

....
```

i think thats the main important part of code.
I get all the data from the servlet that´s not the problem.
Just when i want to start searching for something than i get the 'please wait/processing'label and it stays - nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

This 'get data' ajax php request script has a filter/search function implemented ;)